# Generating column stochastic random matrix with target row sums

Tags: simulation, random-generation, graph-theory, dirichlet-distribution

I want to populate a 0-1 matrix, which is an adjacency matrix, corresponding to a directed graph, with weights on the elements that are 1. In other words, I want to generate an $N\times N$ matrix $A$ so as to target an $N$ vector of row sums(in expectation) and simultaneously all column sums should sum to 1. In addition to this, I have a prefixed number of elements which are set to zero. 
For example, beginning with:
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    0 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0
  \end{array}\right]
$$
and the row sum vector $[1.5, 0.25, 1]^{T}$, I want to end up with
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    0 & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    a_{21} & 0 & 0 \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & 0
  \end{array}\right]
$$
under the following conditions:

$\mathrm{E}[a_{12} + a_{13}]  = 1.5$

$ \mathrm{E}[a_{21}] = 0.25$

$\mathrm{E}[a_{31}+a_{32}] = 1$

$a_{21}+a_{31} = 1$

$a_{12}+a_{32} = 1$

$a_{13} = 1$

I realise that each column can be drawn from the Dirichlet distribution, for example, columns 1 and 2 from $\mathrm{R}^{2}$(Dirichlet distribution of order 2) and column 3 from $\mathrm{R}$(Dirichlet distribution of order 1, or simply a beta distribution), but is there any standard procedure to target the row sums as well?

Comment: Some googling of *doubly stochastic* turned up this paper, [*Scaling of matrices to achieve specified row and column sums* (Marshall & Olkin, 1967)](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN362160546_0012&DMDID=DMDLOG_0014). Most code snippets in googling just iteratively normalize row and column sums until it converges, which apparently will for matrices with positive elements according to Sinkhorn's theorem.